# Where is the `onPaste` for the textarea?

Tags: events, javafx, paste

I've created a textarea, and I want to catch the user's `paste` operation. When user **paste**s, I want to check the content of clipboard and do something to the pasting content.

I can't find any `onPaste`-like methods from the `TextArea` class, how can I do it?

I may catch the `keyPressed` events with the `onKeyPressed` method, and to check if the user pressed <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, or <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, but I don't think it's the best solution.

Comment: I've never tried this (and don't have time now, but might try later), but you could try subclassing `TextArea` and overriding the `paste()` method.

Answer (score 4):

`TextArea` inherits a `paste()` method from `TextInputControl` which is invoked if content is pasted from the system clipboard. There's no specific event fired when text is pasted in, but you can override this method and define your own behavior. The standard behavior is to invoke `replaceSelection(...)` with the pasted content, so one approach would be to retrieve the content from the system clipboard, modify it as needed, and pass the modified version to the `replaceSelection(...)` method.

A simple example that pastes in an upper case version of whatever is on the clipboard:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea() {
            @Override
            public void paste() {
                Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
                if (clipboard.hasString()) {
                    replaceSelection(clipboard.getString().toUpperCase());
                }
            }
        };
        root.setCenter(textArea);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```